# I'm trying to understand how the slice() function and rep() function works together to give the following output

Tags: r, dplyr

```
df <- data.frame(Column1 = c("a", "b", "c"), Column2 = c(1:3))
df2 <- slice(df, rep(1:n(), each = 3))
```

I am trying to understand how the following combination of `dplyr::slice()` and `rep()` copies each row in the data frame 3 times.

My understanding of `dplyr::slice()` is that it selects rows based on the integer location, so the below code extracts the first two rows of `df`:

```
df2 <- slice(df, 1:2)
```

`rep()` copies the values of `df`, and it does it 3 times (`each = 3`). Finally `n()` refers to the number of rows in `df` which is 3.

I'm hoping for an explanation of how `slice(df, rep(1:n(), each = 3))` then works together to copy each row of `df` 3 times. I feel like I am missing some more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`rep` doesn't exactly copy the values of `df`, it repeats them by creating a vector of integers from one to the number rows in your data frame (here, 3), with each integer being repeated 3 times (`each = 3`).

```
rep(1:nrow(df), each = 3)
# [1] 1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3
```

That tells `slice` to index the `df` by these integer values, in this case effectively replicating each row three times.

```
# in your example data...

slice(df, rep(1:n(), each = 3))

# is the same as...

slice(df, c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3))

# is the same/similar to base indexing:

df[c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3), ]
# or
df[rep(1:nrow(df), each = 3), ]
```